# Properly assemble multidimensional ajax JSON into global array

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, multidimensional-array

I have two jQuery AJAX request being made when the use searches for customer information.
I can get the customer name via .autocomplete and I can get JSON data from addressSearch.php, but when I cannot get the values i need from the second JSON set.

The user should simply select the address from the drop down and i should fill in the form.

When I `console.log(address)` I do not get the correct multidimensional array.

How do I select the correct sub-array to send data to the form fields?

**HTML**

```
<label>Customer Search:</label><input id="cSearch" type="text" /><br />
<label>Name:</label><input id="name" /><br />
<select id="addresses">
  <option>Please Select Address</option>
</select>
<label>Street:</label><input id="street" type="text" /><br />
<label>City:</label><input id="city" type="text" /><br />
<label>State:</label><input id="state" type="text" /><br />
<label>Zip:</label><input id="zip" type="text" /><br />
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input#customerSearch").autocomplete({
        source:'inc/customerSearch.php',
        select: function(event, ui) {
                $('#name').val(ui.item.name);
                getAddresses(ui.item.addressid);
            },
            minLength:2
        });
    });
    var address = [];
    function getAddresses(id){
        $.getJSON(
            'inc/addressSearch.php',
            { id: id },
            function(data)  {
                $('#addresses').children().remove().end().append('<option>Please Select Address</option>');
                $.each(data, function(x, val) {
                    $('#addresses').append('<option value="' + val['addressid'] + '">'+ val['street1'] +'</option>');
                    address[x] = [];
                    $.each(val, function(key, value) {
                        address[x][key] = value;
                    });
                });
            }
        );
    $('select#addresses').change(function() {
        var j = $(this).val();
        //fill in fields when select 
    });
}
```

**addressSearch.php**

```
$id = explode(',', $id);//explode address ids
$data = array();//data array
foreach($id as $id) {//evaluate each address
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `address` WHERE address_id = '". $id ."'";//query
    $result = mysql_query($query);//run query
    if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {//results exist
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {//loop
            $data[$id] = array(//build array
                'addressid' => $row['address_id'],
                'street1' => $row['address_street1'],
                'street2' => $row['address_street2'],
                'city' => $row['address_city'],
                'region' => $row['address_region'],
                'country' => $row['address_country'],
                'code' => $row['address_code']
            );
        }
    }
}
print json_encode($data);// jQuery wants JSON data
```

**JSON**

```
{
    "101":{
        "addressid":"101",
        "street1":"123 ABC St",
        "street2":"",
        "city":"Somewhere",
        "region":"AB",
        "country":"USA",
        "code":"12345"
    },
    "102":{
        "addressid":"102",
        "street1":"123 10th St",
        "street2":"Apt 101",
        "city":"Nowhere",
        "region":"AB",
        "country":"USA",
        "code":"12345"
    }
}
```

Comment: "Something is amiss" - you might want to specify that part of your problem. Because now we would have to look through all of your plenty code and check what exactly you are missing, and only after that we can find out *why*.

Comment: sorry about that... I'll edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to walk away and look at it again.  There was nothing wrong with the code above, it was the second parts that wasn't working.

Here is the final function

**JavaScript**

```
$('select#addresses').change(function() {
        var j = $(this).val();
        $('#street1').val(address[j]['street1']);
    $('#street2').val(address[j]['street2']);
    $('#city').val(address[j]['city']);
    $('#code').val(address[j]['code']);

    });
```